# Merging navbar-fixed-top and navbar-static-top

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I found similar questions here about this, but not this particular point.

I have a very wide website, so when I use the navbar-static-top it does not cover the whole width, and when I use the navbar-fixed-top it does not push down the content when its opened

Can I have both options in one ? meaning a fixed nav bar that pushes down the content

```
<div id="collapseMenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-right navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#Home" class="navbar-brand img-responsive img-circle"><img src="Images/C SHARK-white-150x199.png" alt="C SHARK" class="img-size" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarHeaderCollapse ">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#Home"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>              
            <li><a href="#AboutUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About Us</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#OurWork"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Our Work</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#Technologies"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Technologies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ContactUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact Us</a></li>            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use jQuery to detect the height of the navbar on resize and then adjusting the top padding.

Comment: I didn't read your question well enough. Ignore comment. This is a static navbar http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/ and it takes up the full width. It's probably because you have odd classes on your navbar. What is navbar-right doing on your navbar? It only goes on children.

Comment: I removed the navbar-right, it didn't matter, please see the full example http://www.bootply.com/PhOKT1y4TI

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. A `fixed` element is taken out of the flow and therefore can't push down the content in any way. But if your concern is just the width of the navbar on `navbar-static-top`, try to remove the `navbar-right` class from the element.

```
<div id="collapseMenu" class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#Home" class="navbar-brand img-responsive img-circle"><img src="Images/C SHARK-white-150x199.png" alt="C SHARK" class="img-size" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarHeaderCollapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#Home"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>              
        <li><a href="#AboutUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#OurWork"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Our Work</a></li>            
        <li><a href="#Technologies"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ContactUs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact Us</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/S5rUXhPR7n)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, it got stuck on the left of the page, Note that I have a 500% bootstrap container-fluid for the website, divided into 5 20% rows. So when I scroll to the right the nav bar is left at the start point

Comment: Mhmm, I think it would be best if you reproduce your problem in a bootply. It's hard to help you without seeing your complete code in action in this case.

Comment: I created it here http://www.bootply.com/PhOKT1y4TI although the sliding animation is not working, but you now get the idea, Wide 500% container with 5 20% columns and sliding horizontally between them, and the objective is to have the menu stuck to the top and also pushes the content down when toggled in narrow view. if you switch to render view you can see it is stuck but is streched on the whole width and I want it fixed on 20% and moving with view, if you change the static to fixed, you get that but the push down option is no more...

Comment: Do you want the other content to still be 500% width on narrow (mobile) view, or will the content be stacked vertically there?

Comment: On narrow view, the content inside each section will be stacked vertically, but the sections them selves will still be horizontal, so when I push a menu button it slides horizontaly to the next view left or right (This is accomplished already)